# Why does the different order of mutexes for std::scoped_lock affects performance?

Tags: c++, performance, mutex

Note:
this is not a practical problem(I have never locked more than 2 mutexes with scoped_lock), I am mostly curious why implementations of scoped_lock apparently have a relatively big performance hit when locking mutexes in different order.

Example code below, [godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/nxrPGP).

```
#include<mutex>
#include<thread>
#include<chrono>
#include<iostream>

std::mutex m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6;

int cnt =0;

void f(){
    for (int i=0; i< 500*1000; ++i){
        std::scoped_lock sl{m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6};
        cnt++;
    }
}

void f_unord(){
    for (int i=0; i< 500*1000; ++i){
        std::scoped_lock sl{m4, m5, m6, m1, m2, m3};
        cnt++;
    }
}


int main(){
for (int run = 0; run<4; ++run)
{
    {
        const auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        std::thread t1(f), t2(f);
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        const auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        std::cout << "same lock order: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end-start).count() << std::endl; 
        std::cout << cnt << std::endl;
    }
    {
        const auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        std::thread t1(f), t2(f_unord);
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        const auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        std::cout << "different lock order: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end-start).count() << std::endl; 
        std::cout << cnt << std::endl;
    }
}
}
```

note on why this is surprising: I would expect that since mutexes are not movable for implementations to just sort the mutexes by address and use that order of locking.

note on benchmarking on godbolt: I know godbolt is not reliable, I get similar results on my machine in VM:

> g++ --version; g++ -O2 -std=c++17 scoped_lock.cpp -pthread; ./a.out
>
> g++ (Ubuntu 9.2.1-9ubuntu2) 9.2.1 20191008 Copyright (C) 2019 Free
> Software Foundation, Inc. This is free software; see the source for
> copying conditions.  There is NO warranty; not even for
> MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
>
> different lock order: 1074
>
> 1000000
>
> same lock order: 602
>
> 2000000
>
> different lock order: 987
>
> 3000000
>
> same lock order: 612
>
> 4000000
>
> different lock order: 1012
>
> 5000000
>
> same lock order: 585
>
> 6000000
>
> different lock order: 1050
>
> 7000000
>
> same lock order: 675
>
> 8000000
>
> different lock order: 1107
>
> 9000000
>
> same lock order: 609
>
> 10000000

Comment: When using clang, try it with `-stdlib=libc++`.

Comment: Performance survey of `std::lock(m1, m2, ...)` implementations: http://howardhinnant.github.io/dining_philosophers.html

Comment: @HowardHinnant did not read the article fully, but I did check libc++, it works great(hard to tell on godbolt due to noise, but no huge difference)

Comment: libc++ uses what the paper refers to as the "Smart & Polite" algorithm.  gcc uses "Persistent".

Comment: @HowardHinnant do you know why not just order mutex acquisition by address, that seems to me like naive and efficient way to do it... but then again I am not an STL implementer, you are...

Comment: My paper says differently. ;-)

Comment: @HowardHinnant ok, ok, will read it today (in the morning... after I get some sleep first) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have stated, it *is* tied to the implementation.  But the implementation can do better than gcc's *persistent* implementation of trying the same thing over and over again.

> *Peristent*
>
> Lock the first lock and then try_lock the rest.  If any of the try_locks fail, unlock everything and try again.

This algorithm works best if both threads list their mutexes in the same order.

For a higher performing and more robust algorithm, the implementation should use what [this paper](http://howardhinnant.github.io/dining_philosophers.html) calls Smart & Polite.

> *Smart & Polite*
>
> Lock the first lock and then try_lock the rest.  If any of the try_locks fail, unlock everything, then yield, then retry except the first lock is done on the one that previously failed the try_lock.

[The paper](http://howardhinnant.github.io/dining_philosophers.html) shows that this algorithm never performs worse than any other, and often performs much better.  This analysis includes the more traditional algorithm that sorts the lockables into a global order, and then locks them in that order (therein labeled *Ordered*).

[libc++](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/libcxx/include/mutex#L370-L449) and [Visual Studio](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/master/stl/inc/mutex#L354-L420) both use *Smart & Polite*.  [gcc's libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/mutex#L587-L604) uses *Persistent*.

When using clang on non-Apple platforms, use `-stdlib=libc++` to choose libc++ over gcc's std::lib.

Read [Dining Philosophers Rebooted](http://howardhinnant.github.io/dining_philosophers.html) for an indepth performance analysis of these algorithms for `std::lock`.

Comment: As far as I understand [libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/mutex#L696-L732) implementation of std::lock uses _Persistent_ algorithm for C++17 or higher standards if all passed _Lockable_ objects are of the same type which is worse than _Smart & Polite_ algorithm. For standards below C++17, the implementation uses Smart & Polite unconditionally if I am correct. Any idea why?

Comment: Correction : instead of _Persistent_ algorithm it uses _Smart_ algorithm for C++17 or higher which is still worse than _Smart and Polite_. Right?

Comment: I do know that since I wrote this, gcc's implementation has been vastly improved.  Not sure if it is versioned.  I'm seeing yield conditionally used here: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/mutex#L672 .  If the yield is used, that makes it _Smart and Polite_.

Answer (score 2):

When both threads use the same mutex order, no deadlock can occur.  Thread `t2` can only proceed with lock `m1` if thread `t1` has not yet locked `m1` and vice-versa.  No deadlock can occur.

In the case that you use a different order for the two threads a deadlock would occur.  That is thread `t1` has locked `m1`, `m2`, and `m3`, and tries to lock `m4`, `m5`, and `m6`.  However, at the same time thread `t2` has locked `m4`, `m5`, and `m6` and tries to lock `m1`, `m2`, and `m3`.  The two threads cannot proceed and the deadlock needs to be resolved.

In this case, either scoped lock has to release the mutexes it has already acquired in order to avoid a deadlock.  Then the other thread can continue and then the thread has to again acquire all the mutexes and with the next iteration the same happens again.

Answer (score 0):

It is tied to the implementation. We can imagine that std::scoped_lock is using std::lock in some regular implementations.

When you look at the [std::lock doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock):

> The objects are locked by an unspecified series of calls to lock,
> try_lock, and unlock. If a call to lock or unlock results in an
> exception, unlock is called for any locked objects before rethrowing

gcc implementation of `std::lock` is:

```
void
    lock(_L1& __l1, _L2& __l2, _L3&... __l3)
    {
      while (true)
        {
          using __try_locker = __try_lock_impl<0, sizeof...(_L3) != 0>;
          unique_lock<_L1> __first(__l1);
          int __idx;
          auto __locks = std::tie(__l2, __l3...);
          __try_locker::__do_try_lock(__locks, __idx);
          if (__idx == -1)
            {
              __first.release();
              return;
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see, if you have the same declaration order, this is simple:

- t1 std::lock takes the ownership of m1
- t2 std::lock waits on m1 to be freed

In the second case, it can take some time to stabilize (it could never happen theoretically)...